# Unmasking last printed expression variable

Tags: python, variables

I have just started studying `Python`.

I am referring to the tutorials at http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Quoting from the tutorial about the variable `_`

> This variable should be treated as
>   read-only by the user. Don’t
>   explicitly assign a value to it — you
>   would create an independent local
>   variable with the same name masking
>   the built-in variable with its magic
>   behavior.

Suppose that I have masked the variable by assigning it to a number like `_ = 10`. Is it possible to unmask it again to refer it to the last printed expression? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is only true for use in the interactive prompt, when you can do what you like anyway. It's a standard Python idiom to use `_` for a variable whose value doesn't matter. For example, if you are iterating over a list of tuples, you could write `for a, _ in tuples` to indicate that you only care about the value of the first coordinate. This is of course only a naming convention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`del _` unmasks the redefined `_`:

```
>>> 7*2
>>> _
14
>>> _ = 88
>>> _
88
>>> 1+2
3
>>> _
88
>>> del _
>>> _
88
>>> 1+2
3
>>> _
3
```

Answer (score 2):

`del _` will do it.

```
In [1]: _ = 1

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: 2
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: _
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: del _

In [6]: 3
Out[6]: 3

In [7]: _
Out[7]: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got to destroy your local object, i.e. del _

Comment: Talking about destroying an object via `del` is misleading at best.

Comment: Delete its references is more concise.

Comment: yeah, it still needs to be garbage collected, but with the _ lname no longer local you have unmasked it.